# How to apply several colors that line up with displacement map?

Tags: shaders, displacement, shader-nodes

How to apply several colors that matches with the displacement map? I am able to use a mix shader to apply the gold color to the black lines on the displacement and the blue color to the white area. [image: black and white]

How would I then color the inside rectangles a different color like in the example color image?[image: Color]

[image]

you will need to add an hdri in the world shader in the .blend file because I forgot to save one in the file.

Comment: Is your displacement map the top bw image?

Comment: Yes the displacement is working fine. I am now able to get the colors on the inside rectangle by adding a mask for each one and another mix shader node. But it all seems really messy and am just looking for a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Alone, that map gives no way of discriminating between the regions, so yes, you would have to make your own independent mask.. but if there is some kind of  general _rule_ for coloring that it's worth implementing a general algorithm for, folks could have a shot at that.

Comment: If you want a map that is compatible with the "color mapping" without needing any masks, _this version_ of a heightmap image would be more suitable - https://ibb.co/4jY1TYT